# script executing perfectly in terminal but not in cron

Tags: centos, cron

I setup a script for to take an mysql db backup everyday on a specific time, so now the cron is running perfectly it executing the script without problem but the problem is db backup file is not stored in the specific location,but while we executing a script manually in terminal it executing and the files are stored in the specific location perfectly.

I checked the cron logs it's shows all perfectly running, and i check the cron and mysql status it's running perfectly.

help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you using in the script absolute paths?

Comment: Also if user shell is bash be sure that first line of script is #!/bin/bash.

Comment: By default, cron sends the output of cron jobs (including error messages) as an email to the user it ran as.  If you haven't configured a mail relay on your server to forward these on to you, these are probably in flat files in `/var/spool/mail/`.

Answer (score 0):

Can u tell the user by which your are trying to execute script, add it in crontab for the particular user, where script is run successfully.

crontab -u user -e

Comment: yes i setup like that only, but still not working.this cron is running in the user of "backup".So i setup the cron in backup user account.

Comment: can u log the output from cron to text file i mean stdout/stderr output of the job /path/to/some/logfile 2>&1 i think u shoud create this file and give permission for backup user to write into it..and see if any errors are there

Comment: yes i given a full rights to the backup user to rwx permission.

Comment: Can u post ur crontab entry?

Comment: 0 8 * * * /srv/deve/cnjimenez/qa_instance/backoffice/application/schedules/mysql_backup_daily.sh

Comment: 0 8 * * * /srv/deve/cnjimenez/qa_instance/backoffice/application/schedules/mysql‌​_backup_daily.sh  2>&1 >> /var/log/myjob.log can u run cron in every one minute and post result in myjob.log

Comment: Actually we having an two servers, so i written same script for this two server without modification and the crontab entry also same.Here the case is in one server the cron is executing the script perfectly and the db files could be storing in specific location.But in another server the same script is running with help of cron but the files are not storing in specific location.so i think script and  the crontab entry both are right.but issue should be some other. so please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: If the script or crontab entry if any one of this wrong means.In both the servers operation could not be done.but here in one server working perfectly in another server is not working. This was the issue.

Comment: Do u have permission to store files in the particular directory. that is the only chance..Try to log the output and then see..rather than posting here that wont help :-(

Comment: yes i am the admin, i just give an full permission to this specific user to store the files.

Comment: See the problem is happened very recently,before the cron works properly without issues.

Comment: I checked the system logs also it's shows all normal.

Comment: @Tilk Run script manually and see whether its storing files, also check status of cron

Comment: already i done this work. i run the script manually its working fine and the db files are storing perfectly on that specific location.

Comment: But how the cron record this status while we executing the script manually.

Comment: by default cronjob will log into /var/log/syslog, try running cron in every one minute for testing and see if there is any entry in syslog. Just restart cron and see whether that helps

Comment: I am sorry in my server i am not having the directory like syslog in /var/log/. if they any alternatives.

Comment: My server os is centos.

Comment: /var/log/messages can u check in that or in /var/log/cron

Comment: i checked in /var/log/messages it doesn't shows on the specific time, and i checked in /var/log/cron it's shows the script runs perfectly on that time, but the db files are not stored.what i do now?

Comment: If your sure that script is correct, then i dont know what to do next..im helpless, check whether user script can connect to mysql

Comment: yes i checked script is connecting mysql properly while the script is executing.

Comment: @Tilak what was the problem?? how did you fix

Comment: i mentioned this /tmp/.backup_out.txt location in this script.some permission issues happened in this location.Now i changed the permission.Now it works fine.

Comment: Now the cron is running perfectly, and the files could be storing on specific location without issues.